# PyGame - Rendering shapes

Tags: python, pygame, rendering, shapes

I am coding a game called the pie game from a book called 'More Python Programming for the Absolute Beginner' but the shapes don't render and a black screen appears.

I want it to display 4 numbers and when you press the keys 1, 2, 3 and 4 on the keyboard, slices of pie/pizza/circular bread/whatever appear (1 arc and 2 lines).

I can't see a problem with the code.

```
# The PieGame
#
# The last game for C02. Press keys 1, 2, 3 and 4 and the
# pie pieces will change colour! :)
#
# The PieGame was programmed in PyGame
#
# Copyright by wait, who cares, this is just a really boring game
#
# -----------------------------------------------------------------

import pygame, sys, math, random
from pygame.locals import *

# +---+ SETUP +---+

pygame.init()

SURFACE = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption("The PieGame - Press keys 1, 2, 3, 4")

FONT = pygame.font.Font(None, 60)

# +---+ SETUP 2 +---+

BLACK  = 0, 0, 0
SILVER = 200, 200, 200

RED    = 220, 0, 0
YELLOW = 0, 220, 220
GREEN  = 0, 220, 0
BLUE   = 0, 0, 220
PINK   = 220, 220, 0

COLOUR = SILVER

WIDTH = 4
X = 300
Y = 250
RADIUS = 200
POSITION = X-RADIUS, Y-RADIUS, RADIUS*2, RADIUS*2

piece1 = False # state based programming
piece2 = False
piece3 = False
piece4 = False

# +---+ LOOP +---+

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                sys.exit()

            elif event.key == pygame.K_1:
                piece1 = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_2:
                piece1 = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_3:
                piece1 = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_4:
                piece1 = True

    pygame.display.update()

# +---+ MAIN CODE +---+

SURFACE.fill(BLACK)

# draw numbers inside pie slices
TEXT1 = FONT.render("1", True, COLOUR)
screen.blit(TEXT1, (X+RADIUS/2-20, Y-RADIUS/2))

TEXT2 = FONT.render("2", True, COLOUR)
screen.blit(TEXT2, (X+RADIUS/2, Y-RADIUS/2))

TEXT3 = FONT.render("3", True, COLOUR)
screen.blit(TEXT3, (X+RADIUS/2, Y-RADIUS/2-20))

TEXT4 = FONT.render("1", True, COLOUR)
screen.blit(TEXT4, (X+RADIUS/2-20, Y-RADIUS/2-20))

# if piece state flag is true, draw the piece
if piece1:
    start_angle = math.radians(0)
    end_angle = math.radians(90)
    pygame.draw.arc(SURFACE, COLOUR, POSITION, start_angle, end_angle, WIDTH)
    pygame.draw.line(SURFACE, COLOUR, (X, Y), (X,Y-RADIUS), width)
    pygame.draw.line(SURFACE, COLOUR, (X, Y), (X+RADIUS,Y), width)

if piece2:
    start_angle = math.radians(90)
    end_angle = math.radians(180)
    pygame.draw.arc(SURFACE, COLOUR, POSITION, start_angle, end_angle, WIDTH)
    pygame.draw.line(SURFACE, COLOUR, (X, Y), (X,Y-RADIUS), width)
    pygame.draw.line(SURFACE, COLOUR, (X, Y), (X-RADIUS,Y), width)

if piece3:
    start_angle = math.radians(180)
    end_angle = math.radians(270)
    pygame.draw.arc(SURFACE, COLOUR, POSITION, start_angle, end_angle, WIDTH)
    pygame.draw.line(SURFACE, COLOUR, (X, Y), (X-RADIUS,Y), width)
    pygame.draw.line(SURFACE, COLOUR, (X, Y), (X,Y+RADIUS), width)

if piece4:
    start_angle = math.radians(270)
    end_angle = math.radians(360)
    pygame.draw.arc(SURFACE, COLOUR, POSITION, start_angle, end_angle, WIDTH)
    pygame.draw.line(SURFACE, COLOUR, (X, Y), (X,Y+RADIUS), width)
    pygame.draw.line(SURFACE, COLOUR, (X, Y), (X+RADIUS,Y), width)

# detect if the pie is finished
if piece1 and piece2 and piece3 and piece4:
    new_colour = random.randint(1,5)
    if new_colour == 1:
        COLOUR = RED
    elif new_colour == 2:
        COLOUR = YELLOW
    elif new_colour == 3:
        COLOUR = GREEN
    elif new_colour == 4:
        COLOUR = BLUE
    elif new_colour == 5:
        COLOUR = PURPLE

pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: well the main code isnt being called by the loop after a change in key state is detected so the shapes are never being drawn - are you sure the indentation is correct?

Comment: Add indentions (as gkusner said) from line `# MAIN CODE` to the last line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the reason the key-presses are not having an effect is because the code that draws the arcs is not in the main loop. It must be indented by one tab space; however, this results in two:

```
pygame.display.update()
```

function calls. You must remove the first one as it should be found at the end of the main loop.

Secondly, you do not have a surface called ***screen*** to ***blit*** the text onto. Here you must use the ***SURAFCE*** variable.

These edits make the program run, however it may not have the functionality you want. Here is a link to the updated code that works: http://pastebin.com/GFfP2hX4

Comment: why are the numbers drawn really close to each other? the pie pieces are also drawn in the same position :|